# Linear transformation from V=$ F^m $ to W=$ F^n $ As a matrix A: Ax=y for all x of V and y As W.

Tags: linear-algebra

V=$ F^m $ to W=$  F^n  $

A matrix A(mXn) is given.

f:V->W;[f=(Ax)] (A has all its entries in F)
 then A is A linear transformation.

But Is the Converse TRUE!!!??

Comment: Yes: this is true. If $f:F^m \to F^n$ is any linear map, its associated matrix is the one whose columns are $f(e_1) , \dots , f(e_m)$ (where $e_i$ denotes the canonical basis).

Comment: Does this associated matrix have any relation to that of the matrix that is taken w.r.t the bases of V and W. T is the part where I am getting confused?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the converse is true, as you can see from Theorem 11 in Chapter 3 (page 87) of [*Linear Algebra* by Hoffman and Kunze](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-87D9cxiLfibzN1UTRkWTdHVFk/edit).

To answer the question in your comment, the associated matrix in Crostul's comment is the same as the matrix taken with respect to the bases of $V$ and $W$  if the orderd bases of $V$ and $W$ are the canonical bases. Otherwise, the $i$th column of $A$ is $[f(\alpha_i)]_{\mathcal B'}$ where $\left\{ \alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_m \right\}$ is the ordered basis of $V,$ and $[ \cdot ]_{\mathcal B'}$ denotes the coordinate matrix relative to the ordered basis $\mathcal B'$ of $W.$ See Section 3.4 in *Linear Algebra.*